# Why is the very large string that I am storing in Couchdb getting changed?

Tags: couchdb

I am storing an extremely large string (around a couple million characters) in couchdb. But when I get the string via a view at a later point, it is not the same as the original. Is there some truncation going on? Whats the max size of a string allowed? The string holds video data and is the result of a blob being encoded in base64. Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried storing the BLOB as a _attachment ?

Comment: I have not. I was not aware that this was possible. The main problem I was having was transferring it from my client side to the server (node.js) and that's why I decided to encode it in base64. Would I be able to attach the blob to a simple ajax request to send to the server and in turn retrieve it via a get request? Also, I should mention that If I send the  received base64 string right back to the client without storing it in the db, the string does not get changed, so I am sure it has to do something with couchdb.

Comment: Binary attachments can be handled with a simple PUT/GET in CouchDB. Using base64 is ok,but will make your data at lest 1/4 larger. Also you are wrapping your data in a JSON document thatis always using unicode. So to debug your problem the whole serializations have to be checked back and forth. I think attachments will be easier...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up realizing that my encoder was the problem and not couchdb. Below are the relevant details and code to what my problem was in case someone else runs across the problem.

I was using the [whammy](https://github.com/antimatter15/whammy) library to do some video editing and then convert it to webm. The library outputs a blob which I wanted to store in my db and access at a later point. I read that you can convert it into Base64 and then send it to the server with the following code:

```
var blobToBase64 = function(blob, cb) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
  reader.onload = function() {
    var dataUrl = reader.result;
    var base64 = dataUrl.split(',')[1];
    cb(base64);
  };

};
```

My problem was that I had the `reader.readAsDataURL(blob)' after the function. I am not sure why this would make that much difference.

I send the output of this function to my server and store it in couchdb (currently still as a field in the JSON and not an attachment).

After retrieving it, I convert the Base64  back into the blob using the following function:

```
function base64ToBlob(b64Data, contentType, sliceSize) {
    contentType = contentType || 'video/webm';
    sliceSize = sliceSize || 512;

    var byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
    var byteArrays = [];

    for (var offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
        var slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);

        var byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
            byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
        }

        var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);

        byteArrays.push(byteArray);
    }

    var blob = new Blob(byteArrays, {type: contentType});
    return blob;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit strange that the string is getting changed somehow to "not the same as the original" in your words. There is a configuration option for [max_document_size](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/config/couchdb.html#couchdb/max_document_size) that you may be running into, but I would expect exceeding that would cause your document revision to simply get rejected outright. Perhaps you have discovered a bug, or there is more in your codepath that is causing the mutation.

But to get to the point, the correct solution is as commenters on your OP have suggested: [at least] use a binary attachment for this kind of data!

The JSON (body) part of your document likely gets loaded completely into memory as it goes through the system, particularly if it goes to any JS view code, so keep it reasonably small (a few KB or even MB is probably okay depending on how much RAM you have available).

Attachments probably get handled in a more consistently streaming fashion (I'm speculating) although if you intend to replicate anything larger than the average frequency of network hiccups may still give you trouble. Many MBs is probably fine for attachments, but for GB-sized attachments you might want to just store them outside the database (e.g. in a folder on your filesystem) and backup/sync them some other way, like you would usually be encouraged to do with any sort of file-like data in other systems.